# Prove that if for all $aba=bab$ then $|G|=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that for all $a,b \in G$ we have $aba=bab$. Prove that $|G|=1$.

So I have to show that $G =\left\{e \right\} $.
Because for any $a,b \in G$ we have $aba=bab$, let $b=e$. Then $aea=eae$ so $a^2 = a$ hence $a = e$. Because $a$ is any we have $G=\left\{e \right\} $.

Does it work?

Comment: Yes. $\textbf{}$

Answer (score 9):

Your proof works, but it lacks mindless symbol pushing, so I offer two proofs by symbol pushing to restore balance to the world.

*Proof I*.
Write $abab$ in two ways: $babb=aaba$. Then: $$aaba=b(ab)b=abbab$$ And cancel to get $aba=bbab$, but $aba=bab$, so $b=e$. $\square$

*Proof II*. We start with the natural equation
$$baab=aabaa=ababa=babba$$ Now, cancel $ba$ on the left, so that $ab=bba$. But $$aba=bab\implies ab=baba^{-1}$$ Therefore, $bab=bbaa$ and so $ab=baa$ as well. This means $bba=baa$; cancelling on both left and right, $b=a$. Since $a,b$ are abitrary, we are done. $\square$

Comment: Why $b(ab)b=abbab$ ?

Comment: @Arnaud I will restate it with more parentheses: $$b(ab)b=(ab)b(ab)$$

Answer (score -4):

I make it more detail:

G is a group => e $\in$ G. i.e., |G| >= 1

for some x $\in$ G

1, if $x^{-1}$ not x: |G| >= 3 (at least x, $x^{-1}$, e)

$x^{-1}$x$x^{-1}$ = x$x^{-1}$x, so x=$x^{-1}$

This is to say, for all x $\in$ G, x=$x^{-1}$

2, for any x $\in$ G, since x=$x^{-1}$: x=exe=xex=xe$x^{-1}$=e. so x=e

So G={e}, |G|=1

QED

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a group in which a nontrivial $x$ is its own inverse. The cyclic group of order $2$ has this property. If you're in a geometry mood, consider the group of symmetries of an isosceles triangle.

Comment: I'm also puzzled by the claim that nontrivial groups must have order at least $3$.

Comment: tt clear that x = e, if x has inverse as x. or what could x be if x = $x^{-1}$ but x != e

Comment: Consider the group $\{0,1\}$ with operations $0+0=0$, $1+0=1=0+1$, $1+1=0$. Clearly, this is a non-trivial group of order two.

Comment: @gcd0318, there are many groups in which there exists *at least* one element $\;x\ne e\;$ s.t. $\,x^2=e\iff x=x^{-1}\;$ . For example, **all** the finite groups with even order...Your answer is wrong, so my advice is either correct it or delete it.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: no forget aba=bab. what if 1=0+1+0=1+0+1=0?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I added the steps from x=$x^{-1}$ to x=e

Comment: @gcd0318 My example only proved your claim that `non-trivial groups are of order at least 3` to be false. Then again, your counterexample only illustrates the fact that $\Bbb Z_2$ doesn't satisfy the conditions of the original theorem (its order is $2$, after all).

Comment: @gcd0318, either you don't understand or else you don't read: **any** group of even order has an element $\;e\neq x\;\;s.t.\;\;x^2=e\iff x=x^{-1}\;$ , and this means that *in general* you cannot prove that $\;x=x^{-1}\implies x=e\;$ . This is simply not correct.

Comment: @DonAntonio x=$x^{-1}$ is not directly leading to x=e, but just an apagoge. so I separate the steps as 1 and 2 marks. But unfortunately you FAILED to understand natural language. AGAIN: no forget aba=bab as the question mentioned. x=x$x^{-1}$, which is to say $x^2$=e. NO FORGET AGAIN. Then: e=ee=($x^{-1}$x)(x$x^{-1}$)=$x^{-1}$$x^2$$x^{-1}$=$x^2$$x^{-1}$$x^2$=x(x$x^{-1}$)$x^2$=xee=x. So: x=e

Comment: @TZakrevskiyThat's what is to prove. |G| could be in 3 cases: 1, 2, or >=3. To prove |G|=1, just prove 2 and >=3 are false

Comment: I really have no idea what "apagoge" is, and my difficulty to understand what you call "natural language" may stem from the fact that it hardly ressembles english.

Comment: no. you seems falling into modeling of algebra structures, but losing idea to human expression

Comment: With the corrections the proof, albeit poorly written, is correct. Basically, for $x\in G$, $xx^{-1}x=x^{-1}xx^{-1}$; therefore $x=x^{-1}$. Since $x=exe=xex=xex^{-1}=e$ we're done. On the other hand, the OP's proof is shorter and avoids much of this.